# Is there any concurrent queue library available in c++?

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I am wondering if there is any concurrent queue implementation/library available in c++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Intel Thread Building Blocks have one: http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/files/documentation/a00129.html. There is also one in the Concurrency Runtime (available with VS 2010) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee355358.aspx.

Comment: which is better? I just need under windows platform

Comment: @user707414: if you own a copy of visual studio 2010, go with Concurrency Runtime. Intel TBB is not free, but it works everywhere (including older VS). And there may be an open source edition in case you code open source software.

Comment: If you are Windows only, use the Concurrency Runtime (as Alexandre said.) It's fully tested and supported as part of Visual Studio, and it's free, unlike the TBB.

Comment: @Anteru Related to TBB being free/not-free, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362694/intels-threading-building-blocks-runtime-exception-license-what-does-it-mean

Answer (score 0):

[threadpool](http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/)  is a cross-platform C++ thread pool library.